# Get previous 12 months dates if given a datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my stored procedure I'm provided with a varchar parameter that looks like the following:

```
'201503'
```

Which obviously indicates the 3rd month of 2015. However, I need to select the previous 12 months in the same format from the given parameter, including the parameter itself.

For example, if given `'201503'`

I need to get the following:

```
'201503'
'201502'
'201501'
'201412'
'201411'
'201410'
'201409'
'201408'
'201407'
'201406'
'201405'
'201404'
```

Some help would really be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @m VARCHAR(10) = '201503'

SELECT  LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(m, -id, @m + '01'), 112), 6) AS result
FROM    ( VALUES ( 0), ( 1), ( 2), ( 3), ( 4), ( 5), ( 6), ( 7), ( 8), ( 9),
        ( 10), ( 11) ) m ( id ) ORDER BY result DESC
```

Comment: Works like a dream! You've made my day, thanks so much!

Comment: Much more elegant solution than mine!

Answer (score 1):

This could be working too.

```
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(8) = '201503';

SELECT TOP (12) LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MM, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) - 1) * -1, CAST(@Date + '01' AS DATETIME2)),112),6)
FROM sys.columns
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Param VARCHAR(6) = '201503'


SELECT TOP 12 CONVERT(VARCHAR(6)
                   , DATEADD(MONTH, - number , CAST(@Param + '01' AS DATE))
                   , 112)
FROM (
        SELECT TOP 12 number 
        FROM master..spt_values
        WHERE number between 0 AND 11 
        GROUP BY number
     )t
```

### Result

```
201503
201502
201501
201412
201411
201410
201409
201408
201407
201406
201405
201404
```