# Get previous month in SQL when given a varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a `varchar` that looks like the following:

```
'201503'
```

How would I get a similiar `varchar` representation of the previous month? e,g, `'201502'` ? Especially if the month falls on January i.e. `'201501'` I should get back `'201412'`

Some help would greatly be appreciated :)

Comment: have you made an attempt?

Comment: I attempted to ask a question on stackoverflow

Comment: Are you really unable to repurpose the answers to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237775/get-previous-12-months-dates-if-given-a-datetime) to reduce 12 results down to one? Do you expect every *slight* variant in what you're doing to have to be sppon-fed to you?

Comment: Today is Friday and I was feeling quite lazy actually. Also I've only had one cup of coffee so far which wasn't helping me too much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @dt VARCHAR(8) = '201501'

SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(m, -1, @dt + '01'), 112), 6)
```

**Output:**

`201412`

Using [**DATEADD**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) you can calculate the previous month. This function conveniently accepts a string as an argument. [**CONVERT**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) is then used to convert the result back to `yyyymmdd` format.

Comment: Thanks so much Giorgos :)

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @indate varchar(8)='201510'

set @indate=@indate+'01' --Just Append day to date , alway append 1st day as 01;

select 
    case 
        when month(@indate)-1=0 
             then convert(varchar,YEAR(@indate)-1)+convert(varchar,12)
        when len(month(@indate)-1)<2 
             then convert(varchar,YEAR(@indate))+'0'+convert(varchar,month(@indate)-1)
        else convert(varchar,YEAR(@indate))+convert(varchar,month(@indate)-1) 
    end as previousMonth
```